# How populate array of strings to avoid nested loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, foreach

I have to prepare array of strings based on three different set of array objects

```
object1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
object2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
object3 = ['xx', 'yy']
```

currently, I am doing using nested loops

```
result = []
object1.each do |ob1|
  object2.each do |ob2|
    object3.each do |ob3|
      result << "#{ob1}-#{ob2}-#{ob3}"
    end
  end
end

result
=> ["a-1-xx", "a-1-yy", "a-2-xx", .... , "c-3-xx", "c-3-yy", "c-4-xx", "c-4-yy"]
```

Is there better way to populate data another way to avoid nested loops

Comment: Probably a way to do this with `zip` or `transpose` too.

Answer (score 7):

Do you like this better?

```
object1.product(object2, object3).map { |e| e.join('-') }
```

Comment: It's still t̶u̶r̶t̶l̶e̶s̶ loops all the way down, of course. I guess, you fundamentally can't avoid that.

Comment: It could be implemented using (tail) recursion. Or `inject`. Or as a catamorphism.

Comment: ...which generalizes to `arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1)).map {...`, where `arr = [object1, object2, ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to define your array with only one explicit loop. There's no method call with hidden, nested loops:

```
object1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
object2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
object3 = ['xx', 'yy']
n1, n2, n3 = object1.size, object2.size, object3.size

result = Array.new(n1 * n2 * n3) do |i|
  [
    object1[i / (n2 * n3)],
    object2[i / n3 % n2],
    object3[i % n3]
  ].join('-')
end
# ["a-1-xx", "a-1-yy", "a-2-xx", "a-2-yy", "a-3-xx", "a-3-yy", "a-4-xx", "a-4-yy", "b-1-xx", "b-1-yy", "b-2-xx", "b-2-yy", "b-3-xx", "b-3-yy", "b-4-xx", "b-4-yy", "c-1-xx", "c-1-yy", "c-2-xx", "c-2-yy", "c-3-xx", "c-3-yy", "c-4-xx", "c-4-yy"]
```

It's surely not clearer or more robust than your code, though.

Comment: Not very generic solution though - if one adds one extra element to any of the arrays - solution will have to change

Comment: @WandMaker: Updated.